# AS3 how to do a string to attribute

Tags: string, actionscript-3, attributes

how to get a attribute by string? like, I want to use "this.a" to get "this" 's x position.

```
var a:String="x"
trace(this.x,this.a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
trace( this['x'] );
```

Or:

```
var a:String = 'x';
trace( this[a] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a [getter function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000171.html):

```
function get a():String {
    return this.x;
}
```